# Probability - A random point dividing a square into $4$ parts

Tags: contest-math

> A point P is chosen randomly in a square. Join P with the four
>   vertices of the square so as to divide the square into four triangles.
>   Find, correct to 2 decimal places, the probability that all interior
>   angles of the four triangles do not exceed $120°$.

I find this question in a high school Maths competition and I do not know get the answer : $0.21$.

My idea:

- The key point is to consider the four angles at P, since the angles at vertices should never exceed $120°$.
- Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ be the four angles at P. Then we have $$\left\{\begin{array}{c} a+b+c+d = 360°\\0<a,b,c,d \leq 120°\end{array}\right.$$
- If $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are integers, then we can use $H_r^n$ to find the answer. But it is not the case!

I welcome any comments and ideas!

Comment: Hint: what is the figure, in which point $P$ would make $\angle APB$ (A and B are the square's vertices) greater than $120^\circ$...?

Comment: @CiaPan : a part of a circle?

Comment: Right. So what is the figure, in which $\measuredangle APB < 120^\circ$...? And then, what is the figure, in which FOUR respective angles are ALL less than 120°...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You just have to find the area of the curvilinear quadrilateral having its vertices in the four red points.